# Is redundant to use Prism and GalaSoft MVVM toolkit in the same app?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, toolkit

I just was given the task to start supporting a WPF app that uses Prism and the GalaSoft toolkit. After reviewing the technology for both frameworks it appears to me that the designer of the app was redundant because Prism provides a framework that facilitates MVVM, and a container that allows the integration of modules. The way I see it is that each module can implement its own Model-View-VIewModel. Prism could have provided all that was needed for that, and for the communication, and navigation among the modules. I also noticed that the version of GalaSoft that the app  is using does not exist in the official download pageof the toolkit. Could it be that this version was modified from the official download version?

This is te first time that I deal with WPF technology. i.e. a beginner, and I would appreciate any comments about this issue, and a recommmendation on the best way to approach this implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They are redundant in a way: **Prism** provides almost everything you have in **MVVMLight**.

Almost, because I'm sure there are some MVVMLight specific features you don't have in Prism. Prism is much more bigger, it provides a complete framework and approach to build your MVVM application while MVVMLight just gives you tools (it isn't necessary shape your architecture) to deal with MVVM problems easier.

I don't think one would need both of them for a single application, but maybe who made it uses a specific feature from MVVMLight. And it's not clearly a bad thing if the code built with consistency in mind, so *for example* all ViewModel uses the Prism base but for messaging (mediator pattern) it uses MVVMLight because I know a lot of people likes the MVVMLight Messenger over Prism's EventAggregator. But probably there is a better reason behind it, it's just an example, I don't see your code.

Anyway I think it would be cleaner to use only one of them. If this application requires the power of Prism then use only that, but if this is a lightweight app then I suggest MVVMLight (thus the name of this library :) ).

For the MVVMLight version: maybe it's only an old version you have, but you should ask the author of this app.

Answer (score 0):

The two have different goals. Prism aims to facilitate composite applications, whereas MVVMLight aims to provide bare-bones MVVM support. Prism necessarily includes its own MVVM support, so I would agree that using both is redundant. I would also add that using Prism in a non-composite application is probably overkill.